# I added the photos, but it's not responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have designed a website to be responsive on tablet screens, and I've added images, but there is an unwanted gap or bar between the 1st column and the 3rd column that I need to fix. I plan to adjust the page using Bootstrap code or another method.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZkAK.jpg)

Here is my code.

```
<!-- giriş -->
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h1 class="display-3">Lorem ipsum dolor </h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <p class="lead">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisici</p>
            <p><span class="badge text-bg-dark active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus et veritatis, dolores ipsum reprehender</p>
          </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- portfolio -->
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg d-flex flex-wrap">

      <div class="col-xxl-4">
        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/410/300">
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/410/600">
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="col-xxl-4">
        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/410/500">
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/410/610">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-xxl-4">
        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/410/310">
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <img class="rounded img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/410/615">
        </div>

      </div>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .portfolio-item {
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 20px); /* Öğe genişliği ayarlanabilir */
    padding: 20px; /* Öğeler arasındaki boşluğu ayarlar */
  }
</style>
<!-- portfolio -->

<br><br>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example please? Btw: there are only two columns shown, so if you are actually talking about rows (gap between 2nd and 3rd item (row) in 1st (left) column in the screenshot) please adjust your question accordingly.

Comment: I want to place photos according to the grid system. I want the photos to look neat. When the tablet size is reached, the photos move down to the third column as in the added photo. After the third column moves down, there is a large gap below the first column (the size of the second column's photo), but I want it to start right below the first column without disrupting the layout.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification in the comments, this is my answer:

That won't be dynamically possible with HTML / CSS, since the 3rd column (on desktop) is an own container. Naturally, it will start after the largest when on tablet. Thats why there's the gap.

If the pictures would stay the same all the time (so when it's static), you could measure the gap and then put a negative margin on the 3rd container to pull it up.

But when the images are dynamic (meaning you'll never know what pictures will be in there), you will need some javascript to measure the height of column 1 and 2, then get the difference of their heights, and then put that as negative margin on the 3rd column.

Another option is to completely rewrite that code to use sth called [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/). With that the positioning of each image will be completely done with javascript, no columns.